# nginx load balancing localhost

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, load-balancing

I have two nginx servers which are serving images: server Foo and Bar. I want to set up load balancing in a way that every other request server Foo receives is redirected to server Bar. I read up on load balancing in nginx documentation and it seems I should define upstream section on server Foo like this:

```
upstream imgserver {
    server localhost;
    server server-bar.com;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://imgserver;
}
```

Now, I suspect that this configuration will yield that only server Bar serves the images, since whenever server Foo receives a requests it will try to proxy it again. Is that correct? If so, how do I set this up correctly?

Do I need to use another port for Foo redirection? Or maybe add a custom header on redirection?

Comment: Why do you put `server localhost` then? that is not the server you are trying to proxy to!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because I want 50% of requests to be served by localhost and 50% by server-bar

Comment: But this system will serve 100% of requests! and pass on 50% of them. You could make a new `server` block but it doesn't seem to have any point.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It will serve 100% of HTTP requests, but for only 50% of them it will actually fetch the image from disk and return it to the client. The idea is to reduce disk load, maybe I should have clarified it further.

Comment: OK, then it kind of makes sense. But of course you need a copy of all the images on the other server, and a diferent nginx `server` block to actually serve the files locally.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yeah, I already have copy of all the images on the other server. So I guess I need to set up another server block on "Foo" which will listen on a different port